# Dependency Injection Container - How to keep available to

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

When creating an application with Dependency Injection and it utilizes a framework for Dependency Injection such as Unity (or Ninject).
How do you initialize registering the interfaces to the container at the beginning all together and keep them available for the application to use throughout its running lifecycle of the application?
Do you need to pass the DI Container to each method that may utilize dependency injection, or is there some way to make the container globally accessible so that you can register them all together in the beginning and access them throughout running the application without having to continually pass them, and be able to utilize them when ever needed?

Environment:  Visual Studio 2015, C#, Microsoft Unity (for DI Container)

Example Code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Make Unity resolve the interface, providing an instance
        // of TrivialPursuit class
        var diContainer = new UnityContainer();
        diContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>();

        var gameInstance = diContainer.Resolve<IGame>();


        var xotherClass = new AnotherClass();
        xotherClass.TestOtherClassOtherMethod();

    }
```

------ Another class without context of the Dependency Injection Class ------

```
    public void TestOtherClassOtherMethod()
    {
        IGame gameInstance = -- -Container is Not available to resolve from in this class ---
    }
```

Reason:  I don't want to need to pass every possible type that I may need later on to each class I load up, I will just want to use the instances when I need them.  The more deeper I get into classes, later as the application becomes more complex, I won't want to pass down instances for each type up from the Main() method to each class.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? Web? Desktop?

Comment: Desktop (Console app) to test it with, and then Web (MVC) once I get the concepts down.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A Dependency Injection (DI) container is just that. A framework for facilitating DI. You don't pass the container around in order to resolve instances of objects. You just request the type you need in your classes constructor and the DI framework will inject the appropriate dependency.

Mark Seemann has written a good [book on dependency injection](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) that I would recommend.

You register everything that'll need to be resolved with the container in the composition root. That is to say when your program starts up is when everything should be registered.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Run()
    {
        var dependency = new Dependency1();
        dependency.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Dependency1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var dependency = new Dependency2();
        dependeny.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Dependency2
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```

This gives us the above dependency chain: MyClass -> Dependency1 -> Dependency2.

The first thing we should do is refactor the classes to take their dependencies through their constructor and rely on interfaces rather than concretions. We can't inject dependencies unless there is a place to inject them (constructor, property, etc).

Here is the refactored code:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    void Run();
}

public interface IDependency1
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IDependency2
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public readonly IDependency1 dep;

    public MyClass(IDependency1 dep)
    {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        this.dep.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Dependency1 : IDependency1
{
    public readonly IDependency2 dep;

    public MyClass(IDependency2 dep)
    {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.dep.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Dependency2 : IDependency2
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```

You'll notice the classes now all take their dependencies through their constructors and do not new up anything. Classes should only take in dependencies that they actually need. For example, MyClass does not NEED a Dependency2 so it doesn't ask for one. It only asks for a Dependency1 because that's all it needs. Dependency1 NEEDS Dependency2, not MyClass.

Now to wire it all up WITHOUT a container we would just new it all up in the composition root:

```
void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass(new Dependency1(new Dependency2()));
}
```

You can see how that could get cumbersom if we had tons of classes and depdencies. That's why we use a container. It handles all the depdency graph for us. With a container we'd rewrite it as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    // the order of our registration does not matter.
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IDependency1>.For<Dependency1>();
    container.Register<IDependency2>.For<Dependency2>();
    container.Register<IMyClass>.For<MyClass>();

    // then we request our first object like in the first example (MyClass);
    var myClass = container.Resolve<IMyClass>();

    myClass.Run();
}
```

In the second example the container will handle wiring up all the dependencies. So we never need to pass Depedency2 to MyClass and then to Depedency1. We only need to request it in Dependency1 and the container will wire it up for us like in the first example.

So in your example we would rewrite it like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var game = new UnityContainer();
    game.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>();
    game.RegisterType<IAnotherClass, AnotherClass>();
    game.RegisterType<IYetAnotherClass, YetAnotherClass>();

    var gameInstance = game.Resolve<IGame>();
    // you'll need to perform some action on gameInstance now, like gameInstance.RunGame() or whatever.
}

public class Game : IGame
{
    public Game(IAnotherClass anotherClass)
    {
    }
}    

public class AnotherClass : IAnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass(IYetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass)
    {
    }
}

public class YetAnotherClass : IYetAnotherClass {}
```

In these cases there is no need to pass the container around. You register your dependencies with the container then request them in your classes constructors. If you wish to use the container in the class WITHOUT requesting it through the constructor then you are not doing DI you are just using the container as a singleton service locator. Something that should generally be avoided.

**Container as a Service Locator**
This should be generally avoided but if you want to use the container as a service locator you have two options:

1) Pass the container into your classes that need it through the constructor.
You can use the above examples for wiring your classes up for DI. But instead of requesting a dependency like IDependency in the constructor you just pass the container.

```
public class Game : IGame
{
    public Game(IContainer container)
    {
        var blah = container.Resolve<IBlah>();
    }
}
```

2) Request your container through a static class:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    private static IContainer container;
    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get 
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                container = new Container();
            }

            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

Register everything as normal in your composition root using the ServiceLocator class. Then to use:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var blah = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<IBlah>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The point was not "what is DI?" it was "how do I keep the container available for future operations?". For example, take the context of an MVC app, one likely needs to know about the MVC dependency resolver. That's why Darin's comment above is important.

Comment: Outside of the Main() method though how would you use that instance since it's scope is limited to being used inside the Main() method only, wouldn't you need to pass that container or some reference to it to be able to utilize it elsewhere?  (Sorry I am still just learning dependency injection, and want to make sure I understand it before trying to utilize it fully).  Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: My point is you don't need to know about the container in the rest of your app. only composition root which the dependency resolver would be a part of. You don't ask for references to the container elsewhere, just ask for the actual dependencies you need. The container will give them to you if theyre registered

Comment: Thanks Rabid Penguin, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I may be using it incorrectly, can you help me understand how I would use it in the separate class after it is registered in the composition root such as in the following:

`
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var game = new UnityContainer();
     game.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>();

     var gameInstance = game.Resolve<IGame>();

     var xotherClass = new AnotherClass();
}


public AnotherClass()
{
     public void TestOtherClassOtherMethod()
     {
          IGame gameInAnotherClass = new ---[Container is not available to resolve from]--;
     }
}
`

Comment: If you use the new keyword your container can't help you resolve dependencies. Register those classes with the container then request a reference through the constructor

Comment: The only way I would be able to accomplish that without initializing the object with a new object is to pass the instance in the constructor or through the method signature with the parameters. I am looking for a solution that I would be able to initialize the dependency injection container centrally and then be able to use its types that were registered to it without having to have the other classes pass its directly to it. I would ideally like to be able to reference it globally some how without explicitly passing anything about it to the constructor or the method's signature. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want to reference it globally? The point of DI is that you don't reference it globally. You make all your dependencies explicit. You CAN use your container as a global service locator, but why would you want to?

Comment: The reason for wanting this is would be:
If I have Main() method and it initializes an instance of ClassA() to do some job, and then inside ClassA() it initializes an instance of ClassB() to do some sub-task work needed.  But If ClassB() needs an instance of an object that was registered in the container, I won't want to have to pass it up from the Main() method to ClassA() to be able to pass it to ClassB(), and as the code got more complex I would have to pass it further down each layer just to get it to the layer needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer with hopefully a better example.

Comment: Great answer, that makes a lot of sense.  That is a great example.  Thank you for your help RabidPenguin, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Seems like Dependency Injection can get very complex, and seems like you have to think 2+ steps (atleast) ahead for everything you do and over-plan to facilitate it correctly, so you can place what you need in interfaces so it can translate to all layers as needed.  Seems like it could be infinitely confusing.  Is there an easy way to look at refactoring code to implement it (or is it just learn it and practice practice practice to get a better understanding and to get used to it)?

Comment: What if you have something like this in your code: foreach (var item in items) { var x = new Schedule(electricityPriceList); } How would you inject the electricityPriceList?

Comment: If you don't know what your parameters are until runtime you need a creation pattern like a Factory. Example: class ScheduleFactory{}; foreach(...) { var x = scheduleFactory.Create(priceList); } The `Create` method of the factory would handle creating the Schedule. Look up Factory pattern. Though your example isn't so clear that's what you're looking for.